# Lentitud extrema en carpeta compartida cuando desactivo SMB2

Tags: windows-server

Tengo un programa que necesita usar una carpeta compartida en el servidor porque se comparten unas tablas en dicha carpeta que son accedidas desde estaciones clientes.

Cuando me conecto desde una estación cliente hacia el Servidor,  si el protocolo SMB2 se encuentra habilitado,  la velocidad en el sistema es muy buena,  pero las **tablas se corrompen**,  por lo tanto me veo oblligado a **deshabilitar el protocolo SMB2** y habilitar el protocolo SMB1 para poder visualizar el recurso compartido.

Para habilitar el protocolo SMB1,  voy a Panel de Control y agregar/quitar características de Windows.  Luego me dirijo hacia la casilla que tiene el título:  **Compatibilidad con el protocolo para compartir archvivos SMB 1.0/CIFS** y luego marco las 2 casillas llamadas:  **Cliente SMB 1.0/CIFS** y **Servidor SMB 1.0/CIFS.**

Para deshabilitar el protocolo SMB2,  entro a PowerShell con privilegios de administrador y ejecuto:

**Set-SmbServerConfiguration -EnableSMB2Protocol $false**

Luego reinicio el equipo para que los cambios se establezcan.

Hasta aquí todo va bien,  el problema es que al copiar archivos al recurso compartido y realizar algún tipo de operación sobre dicho recurso como crear archivo,  borrarlo,  etc.... se ejecuta extremadamente lento.

No puedo activar el protocolo SMB2 porque como expliqué anteriormente,  las tablas se corrompen.

Esto sólo pasa cuando utilizo \Servidor\RecursoCompartido

El comportamiento se presenta en Windows Server 2016,  Windows Server 2019 y Windows Server 2022.

Sólo en Windows Server 2012 todo funciona muy bien,  inclusive,  después de desactivar el protocolo SMB2.

Por favor alguna sugerencia al respecto.

**Gracias por lo que puedan apoyar.**